# Set environment variables in package.json

Tags: node.js, shell, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I've had a look at quite a number of answers to questions similar to mine but i've not been able to find a working solution for my use case yet.

I've got an environment variable of lets say `auth=false`. i'd like to set `auth=true` when i run a particular script in my package.json.

Script in package.json looks like this:

```
 "dev-use-auth": "auth=true && npm run dev"
```

After running this script, `process.env.auth` is still set to `false`. I've also tried using the `cross-env` package with no luck

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the operative system you are working on, cross-env will help you running on multiple operative systems by calling it:

```
 "dev-use-auth": "cross-env auth=true npm run dev"
```

on windows:

```
 "dev-use-auth": "set auth=true && npm run dev"
```

on unix (mac, linux, etc..c)

```
 "dev-use-auth": "auth=true npm run dev"
```

Comment: Nice to see mention of OS variations. Here I am on a wild goose chase!

Answer (score 0):

This, most likely, would depend on the OS, but for Linux environments you should get rid of the `&&`.

The `&&` indicates that you wish to run the commands serially.

Try this, instead:

```json
 "dev-use-auth": "auth=true npm run dev"
```

Comment: I'm on a macOS and i've tried this but still no luck

Comment: ah, missed a semicolon. should have been `auth=true; npm run dev`. Can you try that?